# Are those theads setting properly?

Tags: pipe

I'm practicing some connections on water lines, but I'm a bit worried the parts I have are bad.

[image: nipple fully threaded]

Here I finger tight the parts and then was able to do just a half turn with the channel lock before felling like it was "right". I'm not sure if that was enough or if I hit the "neck" of the male threads.

Below I show how the tape got after that, in the left side I used 15 turns of tape and on the right side just 5 turns. Both were cut around the last thread, does that indicate that the seal was done? How much tape is enough?

[image: taped nipple]

Comment: The PTFE tape just has to seal around the circumference, it shouldn't matter if a small part of the threads cut the tape. In the past I've rarely used more than about 5 turns. The real test is to pressurize your connection and check for leaks. I much prefer compression fittings -  much less messing around (other than to clean the pipe a little)

Comment: I using PVC and CPVC so I just need to make those connection on 2 shower mixers, 10 connections total, and I never had good experiences with threaded connections

Comment: As per @Ecnerwal (whom I do trust) says these fittings do have a leak path. I'm not sure that PTFE tape is the 'right stuff' to seal this path. I think that some kind of dope or similar might ultimately do a better job that ptfe tape.

Comment: The only dope I could find here is one based on solvents and some kind of rubber copolymer that semi hardens and is flexible after curing. I'm supposed to apply wait 3 minutes and join the connections. I couldn't find any with PTFE. Do you think this works?

Comment: That sounds like it might be the correct stuff. If they are tapered pipe threads, you would only need about 3 wraps with tape. If they are non-tapered threads, dope is the way to go. It hardens and prevents passage of materials through the threads.

Comment: Visually they look tapered, but I don't think that it tightens enough. Also another fitting that I tried seem to "bottom out". I will buy the dope and use it instead.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Just got the dope, it is very sticky  and you are supposed to put it in both male and female threads, wait 3 minutes and then join the pieces. I made a test and will check if it is flexible after curing.

Answer (score 1):

Luiz, to me this looks like it is not sealing and the pipe Dope liquid really doesn’t do much better than PFTE tape.
I have had better luck staying with plastic 100% or metal 100% until the final fitting used to connect the shutoff valve.
The PFTE tape should be “chewed up” when you put on the fitting, if not the 2 different sizes are not sealing and may very well leak.
I have seen this same thing when folks use electrical couplings for pipe (they are not tapered like normal pipe couplings) and they started leaking after the walls were closed.

Comment: Those are metal to metal. The blue PVC pipe has female brass treads in it.

Comment: They are only chewing one and a half turns, I don't think it is enough. I mentioned in a comment above a pipe dope that is solvent based and cures semi hard yet flexible. I think it should work better.

Comment: I would be cautions it looks like the male is undersized or female is oversized or not tapered with the metal to metal they should much tighter.

Comment: I don't have much choice, this is what is available here in Brazil?

Comment: Metal to metal, you should get more than one turn's worth of tape cutting.